# Cannot generate .apk file while running( cordova build android ) in quasar framework

Tags: cordova, quasar

I cannot get .apk file when i use the above command, I get,

ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/Android/SDK
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Built the following apk(s):

Crosswalk info:
After much discussion and analysis of the market,
we have decided to discontinue support for Android 4.0 (ICS) in Crosswalk starting with version 20,
so the minSdkVersion of Cordova project is configured to 16 by default.

Please if someone knows the solution kindly do let me…

Comment: Thats not an error. Its just an info (_Crosswalk info_:) that they are no longer supporting API levels lower than 16. As long as you have set minSdkVersion to 16 or higher in config.xml you are all good.

Comment: Sir after done that. My Corodvo is not building. it shows     /cordova/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
[Fatal Error] kxml2-2.3.0.pom:1:44: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kxml2-2.3.0.pom:1:44: Content is not allowed in prolog.